# Deployment target iOS 9.0 to 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I have developed the application using iOS 9 components(Stack view and CNContact).

While developing on project i have given deployment target is iOS9.0, now i have to support iOS 7.0, so iam trying to change deployment target 9.0 to 7.0 but i am getting lot of errors.

Request you to give me suggestion to solve these issues.

Comment: Used [tag:swift] or [tag:objective-c] ? Also post errors..

Comment: post the errors what you getting?

Comment: Yes, you may get errors due to the difference of deployment targets. Post the errors as we might be able to help more on that.

Comment: You can't use Stack view with iOS 7.0, Since it is available from iOS 9.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/

Comment: Also NavigationController changed quite a bit since iOS7, this could be causing issues as well. In my opinion, you should talk to whoever told you to support iOS7, that iOS7 user are quite a minority nowadays and that its probably not worth the work to support it

Comment: Stack view and CNContact are in iOS 9...if you are targeting iOS 7 either remove it or use @ availability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stackview` and `CNContact` is not available with ios 7. so it will definitely give error. So, find alternate solutions for that or don't give support for ios 7. there is no requirement of ios 7 support because very few users using ios 7 which is negligible. hope this will help :)